# If NP problems are decidable, and decidable is subset of turning recognizable which recognizer can understand them?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, turing-machines

I think the best way to explain my question would be to have sextuple (regular, context-free,
Turing-recognisable, decidable, P, NP).were you fill out 1 for promblem which lies into that section, would an np problem such as chess be only 1 for NP or would also fall in decidable?

Some other examples:
The regular problem would be (1,1,1,1,1,1) as regular is a subset of CF,TR, Decidable which runs in P time and NP is a subset of NP.

Another example, a context-free language would be (0,1,1,1,1,1).

and I assume chess would be (0,0,1,1,0,1)

So my question is would my assumption on NP problems be correct as some decider has to recognize them?

Comment: Chess is not an NP problem, in the sense it is not within the complexity class NP. It's an NP-hard problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct, due to the computational equivalence of nondeterministic turing machines to deterministic ones. You can try all possible certificates in exponential time.